# Custom layout just to override onMeasure()

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, onmeasure

I want to use my custom layout that extends the LinearLayout class and overrides the onMeasure() method like this :

```
<com.myPackage.CustomLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        .....
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        .....
    </LinearLayout>

</com.myPackage.CustomLayout>
```

My custom layout :

```
public class CustomLayout extends LinearLayout {
    private static final double VIEW_ASPECT_RATIO = 2;
    private ViewAspectRatioMeasurer varm = new ViewAspectRatioMeasurer(
            VIEW_ASPECT_RATIO);

    public HomeLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public HomeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        varm.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(varm.getMeasuredWidth(), varm.getMeasuredHeight());
    }
}
```

The issue is that it doesn't display at all the child Layouts, so how do I get this work?
Thanks!

(Sorry for my bad english)

EDIT: I've used this class https://github.com/jesperborgstrup/buzzingandroid/blob/master/src/com/buzzingandroid/ui/ViewAspectRatioMeasurer.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is you're using `android:orientation="horizontal"` for `CustomLayout`(which extends `LinearLayout`) and `android:layout_width="match_parent"` for your child `LinearLayout`s.

Try to change your layout to this:

```
<com.myPackage.CustomLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout_weight="1" >
        .....
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout_weight="1">
        .....
    </LinearLayout>

</com.myPackage.CustomLayout>
```

**Edit:** Also I don't see any reason using a subclass of `LinearLayout` if your `CustomLayout`'s code is you've shared.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work. I just want to keep the same aspect ratio in any screen size.

Comment: Remove your onMeasure method and try. Problem should be on your ViewAspectRatioMeasurer class.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot ! Thanks to your notice about the onMeasure method, I found the problem : I've forgotten to call the method :

super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

So now, it's working very well. Thanks